how is solana price same in all CEX and DEX , where does it come from
In traditional market exchanges, price is determined by supply and demand because everyone is buying and selling from same exchange (correct me if am wrong).But in cryptocurrency we can buy and sell crypto in many exchanges including CEX and DEX so how is the price same in all CEXs and DEXs.How is the price determined and same everywhere ?

there is no direct link between different CEXes and DEXes.
All work with pools (like meme coins for example). They have a pool SOL/USD for example. If someone buy SOL from this exchange, then the price of SOL will increase, only on this exchange.
Seeing that, people (bots) will buy from other exchange where SOL is cheaper and sell on this one where SOL is more expensive, it is called arbitrage. So, if there is an exchange with a difference, it will be fixed right away by bots trying to make money from this, hence, the price si the same everywhere

so basically there are always some people (bots) who are making money from arbitrage ? And for example a new blockchain is introduced and the native coin is mined  so who will come and register the coin in a particular CEX ? and how will be the first price determined ?

yes basically people make money when there is a discrepancy in prices on various exchanges. When there is a new coin, (could be blockchain coin like SOL or a token like WIF), the exchanges need to create pools for this. Usually the coin emitter create (DEX), or ask for it (CEX) the pool. He also provides the liquidity (SOL/USD for example) for the pool. WHen the pool is created, the price is determined by how much liquidity there is on each side. For example if i put 100 USD and 100 tokens in liquidity, then 1 token = 1 USD
